# Add categories for posts - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could you please help with understanding why categories does not working in a right way? So I read quite a lot manuals about, and did not find how to resolve it

I created migration for category

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.text    :description
      t.integer :count
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
 end
```

And added for posts new field - category

Then created model for category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Edit post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_ordered_taggable
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  ..
end
```

Created template

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.select :category, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.name]} %>
  </p>    
<% end %>
```

Edited a bit post controller

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :thumbnail, :body, :description, :tag_list, :@post.category))
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to make sure: did you add a field called `category_id` to your `posts` table? (you mention `category` but it should be called `category_id`)

Answer (score 2):

change this line in your controller:

```
 if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :thumbnail, :body, :description, :tag_list, :category_id))
```

I changed

```
:@post.category
```

to

```
:category_id
```

This passes a symbol to the permit method to allow the request parameter for the category